# Insert an image into an html page without using outer resources using XSLT

Tags: html, xslt

I've just received an absoultely mad task of writing an xsl file that should provide an html page as an output.

The trick is that the only external resource allowed to be used is a css file. The page contains a number of images for elements that can't be generated with css. I know there is a way to embed images into an XSL file as, for example, a Base64 code.

Is there a way to insert these images into the resulting html? %)

Comment: This can be done with CSS and there is no need for tricks with XSLT. Just generate the appropriate `class` attribute for the respective elements.

Comment: Thanks, didn't knnow that's possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use [CSS embedded image example](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/)?
There are many other examples available: https://www.google.ch/search?q=css+embedded+image

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that. I'm a Java developer actually, just having bad times =)))